# How to provision 1TB SSD for Linux from Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, formatting

This is the first time I am both provisioning an SSD and attempting a Linux (CentOS) install.

So I have an unallocated 1TB Samsung EVO drive installed which I want to install Linux on.

I am booting into Windows 10 on my `C:` drive.

I've downloaded the Samsung Magician app but I can see NO options for provisioning the drive.(see picture)

I want to set up the following partitions

- `/root`: 15GB
- `/swap`: 8GB
- `/home`: remaining space

There is also a Windows 10 Disk management application but can’t see any options for defining /root or swap provisions.

Also, assuming I get the disk provisioned and Linux installed, [are these SSD optimization suggestions worth applying as well](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd)?

[image]

Comment: You don't need to provision it beforehand. Leave it unallocated. Just set the partitions during the  Linux installation and let it create them. Also, I'd recommend making root bigger than 15GB.

Comment: You won't pre-provision it, the installer for the distro should take care of that for you, and if you want to allocate space to specific partitions or have multiple mount points, how that will be setup will vary a lot based on the purpose of this installation... Server or workstation, number of users, type of applications, and more would all vary the partitioning, or lack of it, you could use a simple swap/root partition scheme, a separate boot/swap/root/home partition scheme, or something more elaborate. Also, if your looking for a personal desktop install, CentOS may not be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I'm not the only one with USB install problems! The wiki should be updated so others don't waste their time with Universal USB or unetbootin.

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56578

So I've run the Centos 7 installer which is surprisingly user friendly  but have 1 remaining issue. Unable to install a bootloader!

bootloader install failed

Why?

Comment: Solved bootloader issue, forgot to add a bios booot partition(duh).I also assume it doesn't matter if I install my Nvidia drivers before or after my desktop.
Going to go with RPM fusion for my drivers.

Comment: I ended up using gParted